# home page featured product pagination is not showing up

Tags: magento

I am making a project in magento and now stuck up with a problem. My question is as follows:

I have made my custom block for featured products on home page. The products are showing up nicely but i have to show the pagination as may be there will be hundreds of products.

The xml update layout is as follows:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_featured" name="product_featured" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"></block>
        </block>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But although using the same code above the toolbar and the pager is not showing up.

Comment: Seems like you should give us more info. Btw, do you see any error in system.log or exception.log?

Answer (score 0):

Once i had the same issue, I solved this by reading below post

http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination

This post describes how to add pagination to new product in home. You can modify it as per your need.But surly this will help you.